# XML-to-Relational Mapping for Complex Elements with Multiple Parents

Tags: xml, orm, mapping, foreign-keys, relational-database

I asked this question recently at [Flattening XML Data into a database schema with XMLSpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542012/flattening-xml-data-into-a-database-schema-with-xmlspy), but I'm still struggling with it. It's also not really an XMLSpy question, so I'm reposting it in a different way.

What is the best or most standard way to map XML elements to database tables when the element can occur in multiple places in the hierarchy?

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>
    quux
    <b>
        corge
        <c>
            grault
            <d>
                garply
                <e>
                    waldo
                    <f>foo</f>
                </e>
            </d>
            <e>
                fred
                <f>bar</f>
            </e>
        </c>
        <e>
            plugh
            <f>baz</f>
        </e>
    </b>
    <e>
        xyzzy
        <f>qux</f>
    </e>
</a>
```

Note that the `<e>` element (which is complex, since it contains an `<f>` element) can be a child of `<a>`, `<b>`, `<c>`, or `<d>`.

It's impractical to map this to a table structure of:

- **A**: (a_pk, a)
- **B**: (b_pk, a_fk, b)
- **C**: (c_pk, b_fk, c)
- **D**: (d_pk, c_fk, d)
- **E**: (e_pk, ?_fk, e, f)

Because E is actually a child table of multiple tables (A, B, C, and D).

What's the best way to fix this?

1. Create multiple E tables, one for each possible association:

   - **A**:     (a_pk, a)
   - **E_A**: (e_pk, a_fk, e, f)
   - **B**:     (b_pk, a_fk, b)
   - **E_B**: (e_pk, b_fk, e, f)
   - **C**:     (c_pk, b_fk, c)
   - **E_C**: (e_pk, c_fk, e, f)
   - **D**:     (d_pk, c_fk, d)
   - **E_D**: (e_pk, d_fk, e, f)
2. Add a fk to E for each possible association:

   - **A**: (a_pk, a)
   - **B**: (b_pk, a_fk, b)
   - **C**: (c_pk, b_fk, c)
   - **D**: (d_pk, c_fk, d)
   - **E**: (e_pk, a_fk, b_fk, c_fk, d_fk, e, f)
3. Reverse the indirection (this works only when `<e>` occurs 0-1 times):

   - **A**: (a_pk, a, e_fk)
   - **B**: (b_pk, a_fk, b, e_fk)
   - **C**: (c_pk, b_fk, c, e_fk)
   - **D**: (d_pk, c_fk, d, e_fk)
   - **E**: (e_pk, e, f)
4. Add a "parent" indicator to E (example: (2, "A", 1, 69, 42), meaning that "the foreign key of 1 refers to the record in table A with a primary key of 1"):

   - **A**: (a_pk, a)
   - **B**: (b_pk, a_fk, b)
   - **C**: (c_pk, b_fk, c)
   - **D**: (d_pk, c_fk, d)
   - **E**: (e_pk, parent_table, fk, e, f)
5. Consider it a many-to-many association, and build a mapping table for each possible parent:

   - **A**:     (a_pk, a)
   - **A_E**: (a_fk, e_fk)
   - **B**:     (b_pk, a_fk, b)
   - **B_E**: (b_fk, e_fk)
   - **C**:     (c_pk, b_fk, c)
   - **C_E**: (c_fk, e_fk)
   - **D**:     (d_pk, c_fk, d)
   - **D_E**: (d_fk, e_fk)
   - **E**:     (e_pk, e, f)
6. Something else?

None of these seems ideal to me.

Comment: This is one of the situations when a NoSQL database comes in handy. Have you tried MongoDB? It is really a joy to use (there are many others; I have tried MongoDB and it works really well)

Comment: I've not tried it, although I've seen presentations about it, and I'd love to try it. In this case, the client prefers to ultimately get the data in Access, because that's the querying environment he's comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

May be a 6.

```
A: (a_pk, a)
B: (b_pk, b)
C: (c_pk, c)
D: (d_pk, d)
E: (e_pk, e, f)
```

with a link table

```
L: (l_pk, parent_pk, child_pk)
```